# What hook should I use that will fire whenever I open a post for editing in the WP back-end?

Tags: hooks

I'd like to create a simple action hook that fires whenever I open a post for editing in the WordPress back-end. What hook(s) can/should I use for this? The action would just be a simple echo command that prints text to the screen (as this is only for testing purposes).

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Do you want to echo html code or run a procedure?

Comment: @Laxmana OK that's interesting to know.  I was hoping to just echo text right now, as a proof-of-concept test.  But indeed my ultimate goal in this experiment is to print to the screen the 'name' attribute of a particular field on the page ('price'), per these instructions:  http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/how-to-add-custom-post-type-to-woocommerce/.  So I guess my ultimate goal is to also echo HTML code.

Comment: I see. I think you are asking the wrong question. You should search how to add a custom field to a post type or find a plugin that does that. There is a lot of tutorials over the Internet.

Comment: @Laxmana Yep.  Your question made me realize that I actually need to get back to the drawing board on this question.  I still learned a little from Rishabh's answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't what you want to do but here is something that I did earlier on editor page of post type.

```
function wpb_change_title_text( $title ){
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if  ( 'post' == $screen->post_type ) {                //Specify post type
        $title = 'New Placeholder text will come here ';  //Enter new placeholder text
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'wpb_change_title_text' );
```

This function will change placeholder text of title textbox of any post type, here I am changing text of post (dashboard -> add post).

Comment: OK great, that worked as expected.  I will use this to continue my testing.  We can consider this question answered.start

Comment: Here is an another example in which you can add content by default in text area of post type http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-default-content-in-your-wordpress-post-editor/